# Is in a DAG every node an ancestor or a descendant?

Tags: self-study, graphical-model, networks, dag

This is the second question that I am asking here about these note about DAGs [http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/DAGs.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=sml/DAGs.pdf) .

When discussing the max-sum algorithm, they want to evaluate the marginal probability of a node $X$, given a set of observed values for a subset of nodes E, i.e. given $x$ the algorithm should compute $p(X=x|E=e)$.

They start with the following decomposition:

> Without loss of generality, we assume $E = E_X^+\cup E_X^-$ where $E_X^+$ is a subset of the ancestor nodes of $X$ and $E_X^-$ is a subset of the descendant nodes of $X$. (Both $E_X^+$ and $E_X^-$ may also be empty.) For belief propagation, we treat each node as a processor that receives...

My question is why each node is $E$ should be either an ancestor of descendant of $X$, e.g. in the graph :

[image]

node Y is neither an ancestor or a descendant of $X$. The claim would be clear to me if, given any two nodes $A$ and $B$, there would either a directed path from $A$ to $B$ or one from $B$ to $A$, but the plot shows that in a DAG this is not true ?

(actually in the text they focus polytrees, defined as DAGs such that the underlying undirected graph has no cycles, but the example works also for this case I think... )

Comment: "My question is why each node is $E$ should be either an ancestor of descendant of $X$," where in the paper did the authors write this?

Comment: Because they decompose $E$ into two subsest, one of ancestors and one of descendants of $X$. But there may be nodes that are neither ancestors or descendants of $X$ and in that case how can they make that decomposition ?

Comment: The authors write: "we assume $E = E_X^+\cup E_X^-$ where $E_X^+$ is a **subset** of the ancestor nodes of $X$ and $E_X^-$ is a **subset** of the descendant nodes of $X$. (Both $E_X^+$ and $E_X^-$ **also be empty**.)" This does not mean that the two subsets that make up $E$ are *all* ancestors and descendants of $X$.

Comment: Yes, but a subset of ancestor nodes of $X$ are still ancestor nodes of $X$ (similar for descendants), or am I understanding wrongly ?

Comment: At the end they decompose $E$ into nodes that are either ancestors or descendants, but there could be a node in $E$ that is neither of them.